# Coherent sheaves on Proj

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

Roughly speaking , the question is : when a f.g. graded module induces a trivial coherent sheave on Proj ? More precisely, let S be a (complex) graded polynomial algebra, where the variables have (any) positive degrees. I do not know how to characterize the f.g. graded S-modules whose associated coherent sheaves on X=Proj(S) are equal to zero. This should help,for instance,in computing the Grothendieck group K.(X) of coherent sheaves on X (without using Chow group of X) . The standard case, when S is generated in degree 1, is well known,e.g. by D.Quillen (Higher algebraic K-theory (I), Lect.Notes Math. 341): a f.g. graded S-module induces a trivial coherent sheaf on Proj(S) iff it has (at most) finitely many non-trivial homogeneous components.

Comment: As long as you are working with finitely generated rings  graded by the positive integers then there is no harm in assuming you are generated in degree 1. This is because if you "thin out" your grading by forgetting the graded parts not divisible by n, then the geometric objects don't change.

Comment: @DanielBarter : of course, but this does not imply that the characterization of modules giving rise to trivial sheaves remains true. For instance, on $Proj(k[T])$, where $T$ has degree $2$, the sheaf associated to the free $k[T]$-module $M$ generated in degree $1$ is zero.

Comment: Note that q.c. sheaves on $Proj(S)$ are the same as $\mathbb{G}_m$-linearized sheaves on $Spec(S)\setminus \{m\}$ where $m = \bigoplus_{n>0} S_n$ is the irrelevant ideal. So you are asking for a criterion for an $S$-module $M$ being zero away from $m$. But this is equivalent to asking when $M_x = 0$ for each $x\in m$. So the criterion (for a f.g. module) is: iff $m^k M = 0$ for some $k>0$. This in turn is clearly equivalent to $M$ having only finitely many nonzero degrees.

Comment: @Piotr Achinger: Your conclusion is valid if the ideal m is generated by elements of degree 1. It is not the case in general ! See Answer 1 and comments below.

Comment: You may already know this, but  Proj where the generators are not degree 1 gives you what's known as a "weighted projective variety", which has its own literature.

Answer (score 1):

If we change $Proj(S)$ by $Proj(S^{(d)})$ then $\widetilde{M}$ corresponds to $\widetilde{M^{(d)}}$. Let $M$ be a f.g. graded $S$-module with $S$ also f.g. There exists $d$ such that $S^{(d)}$ is genereted in degree 1 and it is esay to see that $M^{(d)}$ is finitely generated as $S^{(d)}$-module. Then you conclude that $\widetilde{M}=0$ iff for any $d$ such that $S^{(d)}$ is generated in degree 1 then there exists $n_0$ (depending on $d$) such that $M_{nd}=0$ for all $n\geq n_0$

Comment: Changing S(graded polynomial algebra) by S^(d) (no more polynomial) does not much help (e.g. in computing the group K.(X)).

Comment: About generateness in degree 1, Iwould like to point out that Proposition(2.7.3)(ii), in Grothendieck's E.G.A.(II) (Publ.Math.IHES 8(1961)), is not correct. One must assume the ideal S+ generated in degree 1.